# TimescaleDB time_bucket_gapfill and get buckets in specific timezone

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I am using TimescaleDB's `time_bucket_gapfill` function to aggregate visitor data of a sessions table to get a time series:

```
SELECT
  count(distinct visitor) unique_visitors,
  time_bucket_gapfill('1 day', last_event_at) AS bucket
FROM "sessions" WHERE
  project = '0b2ba0bd-9f45-40dd-a38a-828ca9c1b2ae' AND
  last_event_at >= date_trunc('day', NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin' - INTERVAL '30 days') AND 
  last_event_at < date_trunc('day', NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin')
GROUP BY "bucket"
ORDER BY bucket;
```

This works fine, but the results returned are in UTC and not in the time zone 'Europe/Berlin'. So for example, the bucket is "2023-04-18 00:00:00+00" but I want "2023-04-18 00:00:00".

I've tried to `time_bucket_gapfill('1 day', last_event_at, 'Europe/Berlin')` but then I get 43 instead of 30 rows in my results. It seems that certain dates get included twice but with an offset of 1 hour. Why?

I also typecasted the results by using a sub query, but then buckets are in local time, but with UTC offset e.g. "2023-04-18 22:00:00".

The `last_event_at` column is of type TIMESTAMPTZ and values get inserted in UTC. I am using TimescaleDB version 2.10 with PostgresSQL 15.